# How to change the System UI color in android programatically

Tags: android

I want to be able to change Android's system color from full color to monochromatic. I know this can be done by hand using the developer mode options [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/74887/force-android-to-display-in-grayscale) but I need to do it programmatically so that it changes for example with the time of the day.

This is different from simply changing an app's color theme, I'm referring to system wide color change, if you change to say monochrome then everything in the phone will display in monochrome.

Comment: Can you delete the may already have an answer? I added more information to show that I do not mean app's theme which is something else

Comment: I understand now. Sorry, no ideas here

Comment: @Juli, did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: @Juli any luck with a solution?

Comment: @Michael There is actually! I honestly stopped looking but I just found something! I will be creating an answer now

Comment: @Juli you are awesome I will look into the answer you posted. Thank you. The Kotlin part is going to be interesting, but thanks for the direction

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for this, there is an open-source project called [Red Moon](https://github.com/LibreShift/red-moon) which allows you to do exactly this.

I have not tested this app neither have I checked out the code but if you know some Kotlin you may be able to extract what you need from their source code.

Also, there is [BlackBulb](https://github.com/fython/Blackbulb) which is also an open-source android project but it was last updated two years ago.

I found both of them in [alternativeto.net](https://alternativeto.net/software/f-lux/?license=opensource&platform=android) by searching for open-source alternative to f.lux which I have used for the last two years in osX